# Firestore: Creating a comment system for arbitrary content

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My goal is to create a reddit-like comment system where:

- An author creates a `post`
- A user can add `comment` under the post.
- A user can add a `reply` to a comment (a comment under a comment?)

I wonder how this could be accomplished with Firestore. My approach is the following:

1. Create a `post__comments` collection which contains documents with the ID of the post.
2. Under each document (which represents a `post`, I can house comments which are ordered by created date.

However, how can we efficiently implement a `reply` to a `comment`? I suppose that we can create a `comment__reply` collection; this approach seems like it will require a lot of querying. Imagine if we have more than 10 `posts` and more than 10 `comments` and `replies` per post. This seems like a costly approach.

Many thanks for any advice you can give to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48820787/getting-list-of-all-posts-with-user-like-and-total-likes-for-each-post-in-firest?rq=1